# C# code coverage for files in test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, mstest, coverlet

I have a project `A` for which I wrote unit tests in test project `UnitTests`. I use MSTest.

I wrote some testing utils in the file `UnitTestUtils.cs` which simplify testing project `A`. I also covered these utils with unit tests.

The file structure now is

- A

  - Program.cs
- UnitTests

  - Utils

    - UnitTestUtils.cs
  - Tests.cs <- (A_SomeTest1, A_SomeTest2, ...)
  - UtilsTests.cs <- (Utils_SomeTest1, ...)

All tests for `A` are prefixed by `A_` and all tests for utils are prefixed by `Utils_`.

I want to run code coverage **for test utils** using `coverlet.collector` like in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows) instruction.
I can specify a prefix for tests which I want to run by using `dotnet test --filter Utils`, but code coverage gives me not coverage of my testing utils, but for the project `A`.

How can I run code coverage for my testing utils?

Comment: Code coverage isn't calculates on the tests. It's calculated on the code. So is there anyway to tell which code in `A` is covered by `Utils`?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to check code coverage for ```A``` inside ```Utils```. All I want is to check coverage of ```UnitTestUtils.cs``` by ```UtilsTests.cs```

Comment: Your unit testing your unit tests?

Comment: I wrote helper classes for unit testing, and they are obviously must be tested too

Comment: why obviously? That seems like a strange pattern. I'd suggest you abstract these out into their own assembly and then unit test that if you want code coverage. But calculating code coverage on unit tests seems like an odd thing to do...

Comment: Well, I found out a few bugs while was writing unit tests for them. Ok, thanks for helping